# Regex: Select everything on each line, after the first 2 letters of the beginning, but up to the dash

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I have several many lines like this:

```
af - miracle asfsa
am - facut asfa
az - ali baba asfa
be - strong asas
ty - asfa asfsa
...
```

I want to select/delete all from lines after the first 2 letters. I made a regex, but it keep the space before the first 2 letters. I need to exclude also that space.

SEARCH: `^.?\w\W{1}.*?`

The expected result should be:

```
af
am
az
be
ty
...
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: hi, Toto. I edit the topic with the expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\w\w\K.+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    \w\w        # 2 word character
    \K          # forget all we have seen until this position
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Beer, Dos Equis. Regex, Toto!

Answer (score 1):

an alternative:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^[a-z]{2}\K.*$`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**OR**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=^.{2}).*$`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The following sed script uses a regex to isolate the first 2 characters :

```
sed 's/\(..\).*/\1/'
```

It works as intended with your example.

Comment: not working on notepad++